# Sed - Substitution in a single line

Tags: bash, sed

file.txt has only one single line :

```
110 ./blabla/log.txt
```

I would like to delete all data after 110. I tried

```
sed -e 's/\.\/b.*$//g' ./file.txt
```

It didn't work, why ?

Thanks.

Comment: it works fine to me. However, why not just `sed 's/ .*//' file` to remove everything from the space?

Comment: Just pass `-i` to edit in-place (be careful with this option).

Comment: j.a : perfect, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a problem with the expression, but to do it inplace, you need:

```
sed -ie 's/\.\/b.*$//g' sed.txt
```

You could also simply by

```
sed -ie 's/ .*//g' sed.txt
```

However I suspect your example is actually not the real line in your file, perhaps you need to share this, there could be characters that your regex is missing.

Comment: there is no need for `$`. `.*` will match up to the end.